# Two web applications in one browser window - one needs to be not refreshed, while second one is

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a website, it's a normal website like stackoverflow etc. Now, I need to add a bottom strip to it, which will contain chat etc. I need this bottom strip not to refresh at all! So how can I do it, so that this bottom strip will act as a standalone web application (webapp inside of a webapp?)? I know about ajax requests, but when I have something like this:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
    //somecode
    <div id="hereIsMyBottomStrip"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

and I will call ajax request, then It will erase all the code on the page anyways. If I would call ajax to change only `body` part that is above my bottom strip, then it will paste whole new page in that section, and that would not compile. How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Use iframe or ajax as you say... If you put "somecode" into div with some ID, you can easily change with AJAX only this div.

Comment: Okay, I tried using iframe, but with no result.. How can I use it in this case?

Comment: Just insert two iframes into this page... One to chat (bottom) and one to rest of page (top). But better is to use another div element, which is around rest of the page (no bottom chat) and with AJAX reloaded only its content.

Comment: Well, the ajax method is a bit more complicated, since this is kinda big page, and changing every link would be hard... If I wanted to put iframe in there, then the first iframe would be put where? On top of the `<html>`? If so, then it would, by definition, contain mybottomstrip in it, and that is bad... I don't know how to design it with iframes, but would be cool if that would be possible.

Answer (score 4):

Your structure will need an extra container is all:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
    <div id="theRestOfThePage">
      //somecode
    </div>
    <div id="hereIsMyBottomStrip"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Then you fetch your content and replace only "theRestOfThePage".

Answer (score 1):

In your ajax code, you are going to want to update the contents of another part of the page, rather than the whole body. Here's an example of one possible html structure, in which you would be using ajax to update the `stuffToUpdate` div:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
    <div id="stuffToUpdate>
        //somecode
    </div>
    <div id="hereIsMyBottomStrip"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```